# Why does Java require an explicit cast on a final variable if it was copied from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, int, byte

Starting with the following code...

```
byte foo = 1;
byte fooFoo = foo + foo;
```

When I try compiling this code I will get the following error...

> Error:(5, 27) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

... but if `foo` is final...

```
final byte foo = 1;
final byte fooFoo = foo + foo;
```

the file will compile successfully.

Moving on to the following code...

```
final byte[] fooArray = new byte[1];
fooArray[0] = 1;

final byte foo = fooArray[0];
fooArray[0] = 127;

System.out.println("foo is: " + foo);
```

... will print

```
foo is: 1
```

... which is fine. The value is copied to a final variable and it can not be changed any more. Playing with the value in the array does not change the value of the `foo` (as expected...).

Why does the following require a cast?

```
final byte[] fooArray = new byte[1];
fooArray[0] = 1;
final byte foo = fooArray[0];
final byte fooFoo = foo + foo;
```

How is this different than the second example in this question? Why is the compiler giving me the following error?

> Error:(5, 27) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

How can this happen?

Comment: Just a note about your second example, where you initialize `foo` from the array and test that it doesn't change. Its value won't change even if `foo` isn't `final`. The assignment (initialization in this case) copies the value at the moment that it happens (1) and that's it. The consequent change of `fooArray[0]` to 127 will *not* be automatically propagated to `foo` regardless of if is it final or not.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The JLS ([§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)) has special rules for assignment conversion with *constant expressions*:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

If we follow the link above, we see these in the definition of *constant expression*:

> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type `String`
> - The additive operators `+` and `-`
> - Simple names ([§6.5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1)) that refer to constant variables ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)).

If we follow the second link above, we see that

> A variable of primitive type or type `String`, that is `final` and initialized with a compile-time constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)), is called a *constant variable*.

It follows that `foo + foo` can only be assigned to `fooFoo` if `foo` is a *constant variable*. To apply that to your cases:

- `byte foo = 1;` **does not** define a *constant variable* because it's not `final`.
- `final byte foo = 1;` **does** define a *constant variable*, because it's `final` and initialized with a *constant expression* (a primitive literal).
- `final byte foo = fooArray[0];` **does not** define a *constant variable* because it's not initialized with a *constant expression*.

Note that whether `fooFoo` is itself `final` doesn't matter.

Comment: But how about the last question: "How can this happen?" (where this = possible lossy conversion from int to byte)

Comment: @KorayTugay Practically speaking, it can't happen in your example. But the compiler doesn't know that; the spec doesn't allow it to make that deduction.

Answer (score 18):

The value 1 fits nicely into a byte; so does 1+1; and when the variable is final, the compiler can do [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). (in other words: the compiler doesn't use `foo` when doing that + operation; but the "raw" 1 values)

But when the variable is not final, then all the interesting rules about conversions and promotions kick in (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html); you want to read section 5.12 about widening primitive conversions).

For the second part: making an array final still allows you to **change** any of its fields; so again; no constant folding possible; so that "widening" operation is kicking in again.

Answer (score 8):

It is indeed what compiler do in constant folding when used with `final`, as we can see from byte code:

```
    byte f = 1;
    // because compiler still use variable 'f', so `f + f` will 
    // be promoted to int, so we need cast
    byte ff = (byte) (f + f);
    final byte s = 3;
    // here compiler will directly compute the result and it know
    // 3 + 3 = 6 is a byte, so no need cast
    byte ss = s + s;
    //----------------------
    L0
    LINENUMBER 12 L0
    ICONST_1 // set variable to 1
    ISTORE 1 // store variable 'f'
    L1
    LINENUMBER 13 L1
    ILOAD 1 // use variable 'f'
    ILOAD 1
    IADD
    I2B        
    ISTORE 2 // store 'ff'
    L2

    LINENUMBER 14 L2
    ICONST_3 // set variable to 3
    ISTORE 3 // store 's'
    L3
    LINENUMBER 15 L3
    BIPUSH 6 // compiler just compute the result '6' and set directly
    ISTORE 4 // store 'ss'
```

And if you change your final byte to 127, it will also complain:

```
    final byte s = 127;
    byte ss = s + s;
```

in which cases, the compiler compute the result and know it out of limit, so it will still complain they are incompatible.

More:

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364465/differences-between-abc-de-and-abc-de-de-de-in-java) is another question about constant folding with string:

Comment: I only had my mobile to answer, so I skipped the bytecode part. Glad you volunteered to do :-)

Comment: Also demonstrates the motive: when compiling to bytecode, the `byte` variables get widened to `int` in order to store them and do computations with them, unless the operands on the right-hand side are `final` constants, in which case the computation can happen statically at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

This occurs because of

```
byte foo = 1;
byte fooFoo = foo + foo;
```

foo + foo = 2 will be answered but 2 is not byte type because of java has default data type to integer variables it's type is int. So you need to tell the compiler by force 
that answer must be a byte type explicitly.

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        byte b1 = 10;
        byte b2 = 20;
        byte b1b2 = (byte)(b1 + b2); 

        //~ b1 += 100;  // (+=) operator automaticaly type casting that means narrow conversion

        int tot = b1 + b2;

        //~ this bellow statement prints the type of the variable
        System.out.println(((Object)(b1 + b2)).getClass());  //this solve your problem
    }
}
```